# How do I have a golang interface implementation return implementation of another interface?

Tags: go

Specific example is here: https://play.golang.org/p/ZNmviKWLwe

I have an interface A. I expect all implementations of A to have a certain signature (hence the interface). I expect one of those to return something useful that implements another interface.

```
type Box interface {
    GetToy(int) (*Toy, error)
}
type Toy interface{
    Play()
}


type CarBox struct {
   Length int
   Width int
   Height int
   toys []*Matchbox
}
type Matchbox struct {}

func (b *CarBox) Size () int {
    return b.Length*b.Width*b.Height
}
func (b *CarBox) GetToy(j int) (*Matchbox, error) {
    return b.toys[j], nil
}
func (m *Matchbox) Play() {
    fmt.Println("Zoom!")
}
```

But of course, it doesn't work, because `GetToy()` returns `*Matchbox` and not `*Toy`, even though `Matchbox` is a perfectly acceptable implementation of `Toy`. And, no, it isn't because of the pointers; it gives the same result whether I return `*Toy` in `GetToy` or just `Toy`:

```
tmp/sandbox721971102/main.go:33:15: cannot use CarBox literal (type CarBox) as type Box in return argument:
    CarBox does not implement Box (wrong type for GetToy method)
        have GetToy(int) (*Matchbox, error)
        want GetToy(int) (*Toy, error)
```

Obviously my pattern doesn't match how go works. What is the "correct" way to go about doing this?

Comment: One of the best advices here might be: Do not try to write traditional style OOP in Go.

Comment: LOL! Yes, quite. I complain enough about OOP, but enough years and you find the behaviour coming back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you almost never need a pointer to an interface type. So `GetToy` method signature should be changed to:

```
type Box interface {
    GetToy(int) (Toy, error) // use Toy, not *Toy
}
```

Now, note that interfaces are satisfied by types implicitly. As a result, by implementing the `Play()` method, `*Matchbox` implicitly satisfies the `Toy` interface (note the `*`, the type implementing the `Toy` interface is *pointer to `Matchbox`* and *not `Matchbox`*).

This means a value of type `*Matchbox` can be substituted for type `Toy`. So what remains is to fix the `GetToy` method defined on `*CarBox`:

```
func (b *CarBox) GetToy(j int) (Toy, error) {
    return b.toys[j], nil
}
```

Now `GetToy` above will return a `*Matchbox` which does implement the `Toy` interface.

Comment: Huh. Really? That was it? Been doing this stuff for a very long time - including in go for quite some time - and the lack of coherence on pointers and dereferencing in go still throws me for a loop.

Comment: Almost. Apparently, I would need to implement `func (b CarBox) GetToy(j int)` and *not* `func (b CarBox) GetToy(j int)`. https://play.golang.org/p/p6KQ5hgQmQ vs https://play.golang.org/p/KtJ3NLe4DO . If you update the answer, happy to take it.

Comment: In your question above you are using `*CarBox` to satisfy the `Box` interface. In the second (error free link) you have replaced it with `CarBox`. My answer is according to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Some fixes: https://play.golang.org/p/-mDr5SDZvV

Pointer to interface is extremely rearly required thing. Use interface - it can contain a concrete type.

**UPDATE**:
If you wish to have a method with pointer receiver like `func (b *CarBox) GetToy(j int)` you may return pointer from `Tester` function (pay attention to **&**):

```
func Tester() Box {
    return &CarBox{}
}
```

This way interface value returned from Tester will conclude a pointer to the `CarBox` instance. Thus Go runtime will be able to run methods with pointer receiver. Otherwise there would be only a value not a pointer. So only methods with value receivers could be called.

Comment: This is correct and helped with adding a missing ampersand. Can you please provide more details on the relation between return type and receiver type.

Comment: @shaktisinghr, general difference is function operating with a a _real object_ via pointer and can change it (pointer receiver) or getting _a copy of real object_ (value receiver). In latter case you can modify only a copy so original object would remain untouched. How to choose what to use? Definitely pointer if you need perform changes. Also you can use pointer if you have a very huge object - so copying will require many resources. If you have small object it's faster to pass it as a copy. https://tour.golang.org/methods/8 or https://dev.to/chen/gos-method-receiver-pointer-vs-value-1kl8

Comment: the explanation seems to be about pointer vs. value receiver in terms of modifying the object. My earlier comment was regarding return type.

Comment: I've seen in code return of interface type. But it's not very good as leads to more complex program. Dave Cheney's article on solid principles in Go https://dave.cheney.net/2016/08/20/solid-go-design